# Is there a way to prefix deeplinking fragment of swagger ui?

Tags: angular, swagger-ui, deep-linking

I have an Angular 7 app and at a specific route I am loading swagger-ui (3.22.1) with deep-linking enabled. when ever I click on a tag or operation it appends the `#/{tagName}/{operationId}` to the base URL of app , Instead of appending it to the route at which swagger-ui was loaded.
How can I make swagger-ui append tag/operationId to the route at which it was loaded instead of appending to base URL of angular app.

Let's say Angular app is hosted at `localhost:4500` and at `localhost:4500/swagger-ui` I am loading swagger-ui with deep-linking enabled.
when ever I click on a tag or operation it appends the `#/{tagName}/{operationId}` to the `localhost:4500` like `http://localhost:4500/#/pet` , Instead of appending it to the route at which swagger-ui was loaded i.e `localhost:4500/swagger-ui`?

How can I make swagger-ui append tag/operationId to the `localhost:4500/swagger-ui` like `localhost:4500/swagger-ui/#/pet` instead of `http://localhost:4500/#/pet`?

SwaggerUI config

```
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui';

SwaggerUI({
  url: 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json',
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui-container',
  deepLinking: true,
  presets: [SwaggerUI.presets.apis]
});
```

Comment: You might have better luck asking the Swagger UI devs directly at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug with swagger-ui. See open issue https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5811
You can fix it temporarily with a monkey patch

```js
const pushState = window.history.pushState
window.history.pushState = function (state, title, url) {
  if (state === null && title === null && url.startsWith('#/')) {
    url = window.location.pathname + url
  }
  pushState.apply(this, [state, title, url])
}
```